# How to get value js cookie from vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cookies

I have one js cookie:

```
document.cookie = "205_45_Single_Premium_=; 206_55_Single_Superior_=";
```

I want get value cookie by vb.net. I try set value js cookie into hidden field but not success. I receive value "undefined".

```
$("input[id$='_txtTest']").val(document.cookie);
console.log($("input[id$='_txtTest']").val());  // receive "undefined"
```

How to get value js cookie from vb.net ?